# No attached service to type named `doctrine_orm_date`

Tags: symfony4, sonata-admin

I'm using Sonata Admin, which worked fine until I rand composer update today. The update removed DoctrineCacheBundle and updated SonataAdminBundle from version 3.55.0 to 3.56.0 and DoctrineBundle from version 1.12.2 to 2.0.2.
Now I get the error message *No attached service to type named `doctrine_orm_date`* on the list view.
My admin class is

```
namespace App\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\Form\Type\DatePickerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use App\Entity\MyClass;
use App\Entity\MyOtherClass;
use App\Repository\MyOtherClassRepository;

class MyAdmin extends AbstractAdmin {

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper) {
        $datagridMapper
                ->add('date_field', 'doctrine_orm_date', ['field_type' => DatePickerType::class, 'show_filter' => true])
                ->add('some_other_field', null, ['show_filter' => true])
                ->add('another_field', null, ['show_filter' => true], EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => MyOtherClass::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                ])
        ;
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Was this removed in DoctrineBundle between version 1 and 2? At least that's the only bigger change I see. I just followed the [documentation of Sonata Admin](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html)

Comment: Same problem for me today. It seems to be a bug on the new package. You can downgrade  sonata-project/admin-bundle from 3.56.0 to 3.55.0 and sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle from 3.12.0 to 3.11.0 waiting an issue. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As HRoux suggested in the comment, downgrading sonata-project/admin-bundle from 3.56.0 to 3.55.0 worked. But they already solved the bug and upgrading to 3.56.1 also worked.